# Powershell script has different results when run via GP and PS console

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I have a powershell script meant to run at logon to help monitor a lab.

When it is run from the powershell console it runs fine, it is able to grab the appropriate system information, generate a url based on that, and submit a web request and get back a response. For testing purposes I can have it echo all of this out in dialogue boxes.

When I run it via group policy the script keeps hitting its error case, and any variables I have it echo out which work in the previous scenario are coming back blank.

Comment: Have you verified that the script is in fact running as the User, and not as the Local Machine? GPO scripts are weird that way.

Comment: No, but further playing around with my script has helped me find the problem. I was importing some variables from a .ini file (in the same place as the script) so other departments could easily change some settings without having to re-sign the script. It seems GP didn't like that, and once I declaired everything in the script itself it works.

So much for future proofing for right now I guess.